# chunking list by delimiter in Python

Tags: python, list, parsing, list-comprehension, list-manipulation

What is the current way to chunk a list of the following form: `["record_a:", "x"*N, "record_b:", "y"*M, ...]`, i.e. a list where the start of each record is denoted by a string ending in ":", and includes all the elements up until the next record. So the following list:

```
["record_a:", "a", "b", "record_b:", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

would be split into:

```
[["record_a", "a", "b"], ["record_b", "1", "2", "3", "4"]]
```

The list contains an arbitrary number of records, and each record contains an arbitrary number of list items (up until when the next records begins or when there are no more records.) how can this be done efficiently?

Comment: You are asking as if there were an "standard" way to do this

Comment: @Alexander: No, I am asking for an efficient and elegant way to do it. Standard is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a generator:

```
def chunkRecords(records):
    record = []
    for r in records:
        if r[-1] == ':':
            if record:
                yield record
            record = [r[:-1]]
        else:
            record.append(r)
    if record:
        yield record
```

Then  loop over that:

```
for record in chunkRecords(records):
    # record is a list
```

or turn in into a list again:

```
records = list(chunkRecords(records))
```

The latter results in:

```
>>> records = ["record_a:", "a", "b", "record_b:", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
>>> records = list(chunkRecords(records))
>>> records
[['record_a', 'a', 'b'], ['record_b', '1', '2', '3', '4']]
```

Comment: ugh - I have an undecipherable one liner using itertools - won't both posting that one though :)

Comment: @JonClements: Resist the temptation to create one-liners!

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = ["record_a:", "a", "b", "record_b:", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
out = []
for x in lst:
    if x[-1] == ':':
        out.append([x])
    else:
        out[-1].append(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's my end-of-work-day crazy itertools solution:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, count
>>> d = ["record_a:", "a", "b", "record_b:", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
>>> groups = (list(g) for _, g in groupby(d, lambda x: x.endswith(":")))
>>> git = iter(groups)
>>> paired = ((next(git), next(git)) for _ in count())
>>> combined = [ [a[0][:-1]] + b for a,b in paired]
>>> 
>>> combined
[['record_a', 'a', 'b'], ['record_b', '1', '2', '3', '4']]
```

(Done more as an example of the sorts of things one can do than as a piece of code I'd necessarily use.)

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import groupby,izip,chain

l = ["record_a:", "a", "b", "record_b:", "1", "2", "3", "4"]

[list(chain([x[0][0].strip(':')], x[1])) for x in izip(*[(list(g) 
            for _,g in groupby(l,lambda x: x.endswith(':')))]*2)]
```

out:

```
[['record_a', 'a', 'b'], ['record_b', '1', '2', '3', '4']]
```